# Prove positivity of chi-squared statistic with general covariance matrix

Tags: chi-squared-test, covariance, covariance-matrix

For a "simple" chi-squared test statistic $\chi^2 = \sum_i (x_i - \mu_i)^2 / \sigma^2$, it's clear that the domain is positive since both the numerator and denominator of every term in the sum over bins $i$ are positive.

But for the more general form with correlations between bins expressed via covariance matrix $\Sigma = \langle (x_i - \mu_i) (x_j - \mu_j) \rangle = \langle x_i x_j \rangle - \mu_i\mu_j$, this positivity is less clear:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{ij} (x_i - \mu_i) (\Sigma^{-1})_{ij} (x_j - \mu_j) .$$

My understanding is that the domain of $\chi^2$ is unchanged by this generalisation; how can I prove this? The inversion of the covariance matrix makes it more difficult to show than I had hoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, matrix notation seems helpful: Such $\chi^2$-statistics can be written as quadratic forms 
$$
\chi^2=x'\Sigma^{-1}x
$$
Take $D$ as a "matrix square root" (e.g., the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), which exists for covariance matrices) of $\Sigma^{-1}$, such that $DD'=\Sigma^{-1}$. Then,
$$
\chi^2=x'DD'x
$$
Let $d=D'x$, so that $\chi^2=d'd=\sum_id_i^2\geq0$.

Comment: Nice, thanks. The "prime" here on $d'$ and $D'$ represents a transpose, as it does in $x'$?

Comment: Yes, it is a transpose.